# .Net MAUI: URL return to Mobile Application(Android) from web

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I have application in web which authenticates the user through different social networking sites.

I am using **WebAuthenticator** package in MAUI for web authentication.

When web app redirects to Mobile app code in not continued but application is opened.

Issue exists only in Android. It is fine in iOS.

Code Sample

```
WebAuthenticatorResult result = null;


// Web Authentication flow
var authUrl = new Uri($"{authUrlRoot}{scheme}");
var callbackUrl = new Uri($"{callback}";

result = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);

var authToken = string.Empty;

if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("name", out string name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    authToken += $"Name: {name}{Environment.NewLine}";

if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out string email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    authToken += $"Email: {email}{Environment.NewLine}";

// Note that Apple Sign In has an IdToken and not an AccessToken
authToken += result?.AccessToken ?? result?.IdToken;
await ToastAsync("returned successfully");
```

When WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync is called code below it are not executed after returning from web.
In iOS, it is executing but android it is not.

Comment: Did you follow precisely the platform setup here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?tabs=android#get-started ?

Comment: Another question, does this happen with chrome browser?

Comment: It seems, i was having issue while creating redirect url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mobile I was using callback url as app://com.company.appname

In web I was Redirecting to app://com.company.appname#key=value

Instead, I am using callback url as appname and I am Redirecting to appname://#key=value

This has fixed my issue.