# Web authenticator with MAUI (.NET 8)

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

I'm trying to use the Web authenticator in a MAUI project built with .NET 8. I followed the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#get-started).

I created the API using the code from the documentation and published it on a public website. Then, I configured the MAUI app following the documentation.

The result is when I try to log in with Microsoft (the only provider I was trying), the first time I have been asked to insert my Microsoft account. Although I closed the app and reopen it, then I tried to log in, I got an error "too many redirections" as you see in the following screenshot.

[image]

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76996860/net-maui-url-return-to-mobile-applicationandroid-from-web) but it is not clear to me what the fix is. Plus, from the documentation, the Web authenticator doesn't work with Windows. DO you know if there is any workaround?

Comment: If it's .net7, will it work well?

Comment: Never tried with NET7. This is my first time with Web Authenticator. I tried on a real device and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: You could try to creat a project via net7, see if it runs well.